# Is is always true that $\sum_{1}^{n}\left ( a_{i}-\bar{a} \right )^2\leq \sum_{1}^{n}a_{i}^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it always true that
$$\sum_{1}^{n}\left ( a_{i}-\bar{a} \right )^2\leq \sum_{1}^{n}a_{i}^2$$

where $\bar{a}$ is  the mean of all $a_{i}$'s.

If yes, how to prove it?

Comment: An explicit computation gives $\sum (a_i - \overline{a})^2 = \sum a_i^2 - n \overline{a}^2$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum a_i^2-\sum(a_i-\bar a)^2=\sum2a_i\bar a-\sum\bar a^2$$$$=-n\bar a^2+2\bar a\sum a_i=-n\bar a^2+2\bar a(n\bar a)=n\bar a^2\geq0$$